# Using Genetic Algorithm to converge to global minimum of a 2 variable function

Tags: c++, algorithm, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

I am using Visual Studio C++ as the platform to try to converge to the global minimum.

Let's assume the function is a blackbox function where in if I input (x,y), I get z.

And also that the algorithm used is a real value genetic algorithm where I'm not converting the samples to binary codes but instead into floating points.

https://karczmarczuk.users.greyc.fr/TEACH/IAD/GenDoc/carrGenet.pdf

I have used the algorithm mentioned in there in appendix B. For finding the minimum of a 2 - variable function.

f(x,y) = z

I have done a grid value search to get the graph of the problem. I have attached the graph.

[image: f(x,y) = z]

Here the minimum value of the graph as you can see from the graph is only at **one point** of (0.6, 1.3).

The algorithm converges if I use discrete values of (x,y) in multiples of 0.1. For eg. 0.8,0.9,2.2,5.6 etc. But otherwise it does not converge.

Is there anyway I can modify the graph to fit the algorithm or if I can modify the algorithm to minimize the function?

Comment: Why would you modify the graph? It's like photoshopping your house to make it bigger when you want more space in your home. And what algorithm?

Comment: @plasmacel I initially took the logarithm of z to obtain this graph. If there was any other way to again further process it so that it's easy for the algorithm to converge.

Comment: You provide no information about the function you want to minimize, nor the minimization algorithm. How do you expect help?

Comment: Without knowing what the algorithm is it is impossible to discus how it may be modified or accommodated.

Comment: I assume the OP thinks that he created the graph in a wrong way, that's why he didn't get proper results. Anyway, more information is needed.

Comment: @Galik I am using a real valued genetic algorithm to solve the problem. The problem is since the global minimum is at just one single point and not it's neighboring points, it is difficult to converge to that.

Comment: @plasmacel Yes. For instance the graph seems to converge to the minimas to the right because the neighboring points to the local minima leads to it. However for the Global minima, since it is at only one point and the neighboring points do not provide any information, shouldn't it be difficult for the algorithm to converge?

Comment: @RahulKaruppiah The term genetic algorithm is only a class, an approach of algorithms, not a specific algorithm. And even if it would be a specific one, there are probably multiple possible implementations of it. Maybe the algorithm is buggy. You need to update your question with its implementation and also the function you want to minimize.

Comment: There is more than one "real valued genetic algorithm" you'll need to be specific.

Comment: @Galik I have used the algorithm mentioned in example 2.3 in page 11 or Appendix B in https://karczmarczuk.users.greyc.fr/TEACH/IAD/GenDoc/carrGenet.pdf

It's used for converging to the minimum of a 2 variable function

Comment: @plasmacel I have updated as to which particular algorithm I have used. Also I have checked the validity of the algorithm by plugging in various other functions and finding it's minima. That's why I'm doubtful as to maybe it's my function or graph that needs processing and not the algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

your global optimum here is very pointy. you need a lot of luck to fall in it (ie. a lot of random individuals with actually little chance to find it).

if you manage to get an individual on the slope, the GA will converge to the optimum. so I would advise to get a smoother optimum or try more random values.

Comment: Is there any way I can refine my graph to get it a smoother slope or is there any other algorithms that I can try for this?

Comment: We can't know if we can make it smoother without knowing the function explicitly. Also knowing the problem domain might help too.

Comment: @Ray There is no explicit function, this graph basically tries to co-relate 2 input variables in my simulation to one of the outputs. I scanned the function in the domain of x - (-2,2) and y - (0.5,10) with a width of 0.05 and plotted it against the output. That's how I obtained this graph.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you consider the random number generator part of the black-box, so is there structure to your input function that you could represent in the random initialization or in the way the random mutations occur?

Comment: Since most of the extremes of the functions are concentrated on one part of the graph, I think each iteration makes it closer to that region. The mutations are randomly generated within the same sample space.

Comment: @RahulKaruppiah I've come across the idea of a 'jumping mutator'. [Here](https://github.com/orthopteroid/psychic-sniffle) is some code that uses byte-distributions from the phenotypes to perform mutations, and for random population synthesis.